# Can Resharper ignore spaces in declaration statements?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I prefer using Align Assignments

Aligns assignment statements by typing Ctrl+Alt+]. For example, typing Ctrl-Alt-] when the following is selected:

```
        MaxMultiplier = bonusMathModel.MaxMultiplier;
        MaxFreeGames = bonusMathModel.MaxFreeGames;
        MultiplierQueueMode = MultiplierQueueMode.OVERLAPPED;
        OverlappedMultiplierOperator = OverlappedMultiplierOperator.ADDED;
```

Transforms it into this:

```
        MaxMultiplier                = bonusMathModel.MaxMultiplier;
        MaxFreeGames                 = bonusMathModel.MaxFreeGames;
        MultiplierQueueMode          = MultiplierQueueMode.OVERLAPPED;
        OverlappedMultiplierOperator = OverlappedMultiplierOperator.ADDED;
```

However, Resharper ctrl-alt-f cleanup will undo the align assignments. How can I change Resharper's behavior so that it preserves Align assignments?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to create a new Clean-up profile with Reformat Code set to No and use that instead.

You can't mix and match the convenience of automatic reformatting with custom spacing. Resharper isn't to know which additional spaces are deliberate and which are accidental.